# Notes search : search syntax multiple words for a field in FTSearch

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I'd like to search multiple words in a field by FTSearch.

Currently I wrote as follows.
[Field1]=dog or [Field1]=cat or [Field1]=bird or [Field1]=fish or [Field1]=cow or [Field1]=snake

I looked for good syntaxes in help but not found. Are there any good syntax?

Comment: Is your full text index up to date? You could try placing the values in quotes:`[Field1] = "cat"`. I take it Field1 is the name of the actual field that contains these values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is correct, you only have to use double quotes if you want to search for fixed groups of words or special characters.

The syntax is explained in the Notes client help.nsf database, not in the Designer help.

See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSKTWP_9.0.1/sch_refine_query_r.html